# Programmatically get cloud spending/balance for AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, faas

Is there a way to get current status from an AWS account either through AWS cli or programmatically?

I am conducting some research in relation to FaaS and would like to get and log the cost after each experiment but haven't been able to find a solution for this.

Would really appreciate if somebody could point me in the right direction here :)

Thanks

Comment: Start with AWS Cost and avoid AWS curent Status.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the [AWS Cost Explorer Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) with the Cost Management API.

Also, [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cost-explorer-report) is an example of a fully fledged reporting tool written in Python.

But be aware that those [AWS Cost Management API](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/pricing/) calls also incur costs ($0.01 per report) that are most likely higher than the [AWS Lambda costs](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/?nc1=h_ls) itself:

Lambda costs: $0.20 per 1M requests + $0.0000166667 for every GB-second